# SQL QUERY - Time comparison (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, time

I would like to ask if someone would be able to help with sql query. I have table with times in format: HH:MM:SS. I want to write a query that returns me the closest time (to the future) to the current time. For example: Table contains 3 rows: 12:00:00, 12:01:00, 12:02:00. If:

1) Current time is: 12:00:30. The query returns: 12:01:00., etc.

BUT!

2) Current time is: 12:02:30. The query returns: 12:00:00.

I write this query, whitch solves me 1), but not 2).

```
select time(myColumn) 
from myTable 
where time(myColumn) >= time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') 
order by myColumn 
limit 1
```

I would appreciate if someone could help.

PS: Database is in SQLite (must be) and is not possible to calculate with dates eg: 2011-01-01 12:00:00...)

Thank you Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! This is the query:

```
select 
case when 
(select min(time(myColumn)) from myTable where time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') < time(myColumn)) is null 
then 
(select min(time(myColumn)) from myTable where time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') > time(myColumn)) 
else 
(select min(time(myColumn)) from myTable where time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') < time(myColumn)) 
end
```

Thx Tim & Dave who showed me the way.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
             select min(  time(yourtimecolumn) ) from foo
             where time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') < time(yourtimecolumn)
```

Edited by Tom

Comment: It is possible that it's that easy! :) Thank you for your help. You are lifesaver! There is only synthax error '(' after the WHERE clause.

Comment: Unfortunately I found problem with this query, after few tests. When the current time is eg: 21:00:00 and there is 3 rows in database eg: 01:00:00, 01:20:00, 02:30:00, query returns null.

Comment: @Tom: But all of those times are not greater than 21:00:00. They are in the very early morning and 21:00:00 is in the evening. You had asked for *future* time: `I want to write a query that returns me the closest time (to the future) to the current time.`  So maybe it's just a misunderstanding of your requirement.

Comment: Yes, i know. Imagine a bus timetable database, where are stored  departure times. What I need to find is the closest departure time (of course future time). Sorry if the question is misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: if you need to get the NEXT closest time, try:

```
SELECT time(myColumn)
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myColumn - time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') > 0,
         THEN myColumn - time(current_timestamp, 'localtime')
         ELSE myColumn - time(current_timestamp, '24 hours', 'localtime')
         END CASE
LIMIT 1
```

It sorts by the amount of time to the next timestamp in the database, attempting to add 24 hours if necessary to get a positive number (an upcoming time) as a result.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work. I have 3 times: 16:24:00, 16:25:00, 20:12:00. Current time is 20:16:00. Return of the query is 20:12:00 (should be 16:24:00). I ment closest (but to the future, I'm sorry if I have mystified you).

Comment: Ah, you mean like price is right style (or the opposite? lol i dunno).  try this...

Comment: There is some synthax error, but even if i correct to: SELECT time(myColumn) FROM myTable ORDER BY CASE WHEN myColumn - time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') > 0 THEN myColumn - time(current_timestamp, 'localtime') ELSE myColumn - time(current_timestamp, '24 hours', 'localtime') END LIMIT 1 it doesn't work. Once again: Current time is for example: 22:00:00. Database database has 3 entries: 08:00:00, 12:00:00, 23:00:00. When I run the query at 22:00:00 (current time), result should be 23:00:00. Q: 23:00:01, R: 08:00:00, Q: 9:00:00, R: 12:00:00, etc. Anyway, thank you for helping me!!!